# Можно ли добавить javaс в контекстное меню проводника?

Tags: java, windows, консоль, javac

Можно ли добавить javaс в контекстное меню проводника? Или хотя бы как создать батник, который будет компилировать все файлы java находящиеся в директории.

Comment: Опишите подробнее, зачем это нужно?

Comment: Зачем нужен батник, если это делается в одну строку - `javac *.java`?

Answer (score 0):

Пишем батник с единственной строкой:

```
javac *.java
```

Качаем программу Context Menu tuner(далее CMT) или любую другую, или ручками через regdit

Пример с CMT:

1 Запускаем CMT в правом окошке выбираем "Папка" в левом "Add custom item"

2 Жмем add>> что находиться между двух окошек и получаем форму

3 Заполняем форму

- В поле "Menu item title" вводим название которое будет отображаться в
  контекстном меню;
- В поле Executable File Path путь к батнику

4 Жмем Create - и получаем желаемое

Итог: кнопка в контекстном меню по нажатию на которую будут компилиться все файлы в папке